# Быстрая сортировка Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

объясните пожалуйста, что значат эти строки:

```
less = [i for i in array[1:] if i <= pivot]
greater = [i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot]
```

Вот весь код:

```
def quickSort(array):
if len(array) < 2:
    return array
else:
    pivot = array[0]
    less = [i for i in array[1:] if i <= pivot]
    greater = [i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot]
    return quickSort(less) + [pivot] + quickSort(greater)
```

Comment: В `less` пишем елементы массива `array` начиная от первого, если `i <= pivot`, так же с `greater` - только, если `>`. [Тут](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/) более рассписано как работает quicksort

Comment: @entithat array[1:] означает пройти весь массив от 1 по индексу числа?

Comment: `array[1:]` означает вернуть массив с елементами начиная от первого. Проходимся уже по елементах мы циклом `for`.